# JPanel.getGraphics equivalent in JavaFx to use with OpenCV

Tags: swing, opencv, javafx, jpanel, pane

The title seems a little bit confusing, but I'll explain everything.

I'm developing a project where I show the image captured by a webcam in a JPanel, Java Swing. Now I have to integrate this with JavaFx.
I have a controller where I have the method startRecording, that would initialize the cameraThread and tell the class Camera to startRecording, inside Camera class a have a method DrawFrame(BufferedImage, JPanel panel) where I call the function drawImage from OpenCV to draw in the Panel:

Controller:

```
public void startRecording(){
    cameraInstance.setCameraRGBPanel(windowsInstance.getCameraRGBPanel());
    cameraInstance.setCameraHSVPanel(windowsInstance.getCameraHSVPanel());
    cameraInstance.setCameraThresholdPanel(windowsInstance.getCameraThresholdPanel());
    cameraInstance.setRecord(true);
    cameraThread = new Thread(cameraInstance);
    cameraThread.start();
}
```

Class camera:

```
private void drawFrame(BufferedImage buff, JPanel pane){
    pane.getGraphics().drawImage(buff, 0, 0, null);
}
```

To start with, JavaFX has no JPanel and the Pane (an option) has no getGraphics, I've tried to use a SwingNode, add the JPanel and then do everything as usual, but the image simply won't be shown.

The following code was a test, that's why it seems to be so 'bad'.

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    stage.setTitle("Tela Teste");

    pCamera = new Pane();
    SwingNode swing = new SwingNode();
    pCamera.getChildren().add(swing);
    createAndSetSeingContent(swing);

    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().add(pCamera);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root , 500, 500));
    stage.setResizable(true);
    stage.show();
}

private void createAndSetSeingContent(SwingNode swing) {                
    ControllerCamera control = new ControllerCamera();
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Abc");
    //panel.add(label);
    swing.setContent(panel);

    Button teste = new Button("A");
    pCamera.getChildren().add(teste);
    teste.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            control.startRecording(panel);
            System.out.println("abc");
        }
    });
}
```

I changed to method startRecording to something like:

```
public void startRecording(JPanel panel){
    cameraInstance.setCameraRGBPanel(panel);
    cameraInstance.setRecord(true);
    cameraThread = new Thread(cameraInstance);
    cameraThread.start();
}
```

Still nothing appears in the panel, but if I add a label or button, then it appear and works as intended to. The "abc" is always shown in the console.

I think that's all the code related to the problem. Something else I want to say is that yesterday was the first day I was dealing with FX, let's say the project is divided, the other guy is also working on the problem, but we haven't gotten anywhere so far, that's why I decided to ask you here.

Edit 1: everything was working perfectly before all this situation (everything works with Swing, but not in FX).

Comment: You can display an image in JavaFX by using an [`ImageView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) and calling `setImage(...)`. You will either have to generate `javafx.scene.image.Image` directly, or convert a `java.awt.iamge.BufferedImage` to a JavaFX image using [`SwingFXUtils.toFXImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#toFXImage-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-)

Comment: Trying it right now.

Comment: it worked. I'm sorry it was this simple, I was just desperate to solve a problem in an environment I don't know. Please, post is as an answer so I can mark it as the final answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to display an Image in JavaFX is with an [`ImageView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html). You can create a single `ImageView` and update its image by calling `setImage(...)`, passing in a `javafx.scene.image.Image`. I don't know the camera API you are working with: you might be able to generate a JavaFX image directly, in which case your draw frame method looks as simple as:

```
private void drawFrame(Image image, ImageView imageView) {
    imageView.setImage(image);
}
```

If you can only generate `BufferedImage`s, you can do

```
private void drawFrame(BufferedImage buff, ImageView imageView) {
    imageView.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(buff, null));
}
```

In either case, you can just create the `ImageView`, put it in a `Pane` subclass of some kind, put the `Pane` in a scene and display it in the `Stage`:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    stage.setTitle("Tela Teste");

    pCamera = new Pane();
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    pCamera.getChildren().add(imageView);

    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().add(pCamera);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root , 500, 500));
    stage.setResizable(true);
    stage.show();
}
```

Then just pass the `imageView` to your `drawFrame` method as needed.

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot. I simply had to transform from Mat (OpenCV) to BufferedImage (because I need it in some other methods) and in this one I convert it to Image from FX.